# Do not selected Duplicate line (or text) in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

After I reinstalled VS (after upgrading to Windows 10), I found out I can't assign a shortcut keys to the command duplicate, I already made it before in the same version: I assigned ctrl + D to that command, but now I can't find it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2v3S.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Xsk.png)